# What is the best way to use a theme in styled components for a single themed app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, styled-components, emotion

I've always accessed the theme in a styled component as the official styled components instructs

```js
const Button = styled.button`
  color: ${props => props.theme.main};
  border: 2px solid ${props => props.theme.main};
`;
```

But I was wondering if there's any advantage or disadvantage on importing it directly from it's declaration file like so

```js
import theme from "src/theme";

const Button = styled.button`
  color: ${theme.main};
  border: 2px solid ${theme.main};
`;
```

In the scenario of a single themed app, what's the best approach?